# Format of cookies when using wget?

Tags: wget

What's the Netscape format of `wget`'s `cookies.txt`? I need to mirror a website that requires login. 
I use a Chrome extension that returns cookies in that format, I save them in `cookies.txt`, import with `wget` command but to no use, it just downloads the content like I'm not logged in at all.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The format is Netscape format as stated in the man page and this format is:

> The layout of Netscape's cookies.txt file is such that each line
>   contains one name-value pair. An example cookies.txt file may have an
>   entry that looks like this:
>
> `.netscape.com   TRUE   /   FALSE   946684799   NETSCAPE_ID   100103`
>
> Each line represents a single piece of stored information. A *tab* is
>   inserted between each of the fields.
>
> From left-to-right, here is what each field represents:
>
> **domain** - The domain that created AND that can read the variable.
>
> **flag** - A TRUE/FALSE value indicating if all machines within a given domain can access the variable. This value is set automatically by the
>   browser, depending on the value you set for domain.
>
> **path** - The path
>   within the domain that the variable is valid for.
>
> **secure** - A
>   TRUE/FALSE value indicating if a secure connection with the domain is
>   needed to access the variable.
>
> **expiration** - The UNIX time that the
>   variable will expire on. UNIX time is defined as the number of seconds
>   since Jan 1, 1970 00:00:00 GMT.
>
> **name** - The name of the variable.
>
> **value**
>   - The value of the variable.

(From "[The Unofficial Cookie FAQ](http://www.cookiecentral.com/faq/)", edited for clarity)

Comment: Is the file Tab or Space seperated?

Comment: @ferrybig Tabs are used.

Comment: anything special is the cookie comes from e.g. 127.0.0.1 instead of something with a domain name ?

Comment: Apparently you also have to [put a "bash comment"](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/4539#issuecomment-79135589) at the top of the file saying `# Netscape HTTP Cookie File` for some programs to even recognize it as a cookie file.

Answer (score 6):

The Netscape cookies file format for each data line is as above, but you won't be able to read it in with `HTTP::Cookies::Netscape` unless it has a header line like this, which the complete file format requires:

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
```

or this:

```
# HTTP Cookie File
```

Comment: this is such black voodoo... do you have a reference to where in docs it is mentioned? it's not in curl docs (https://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html) and none of the pages linked in there... (it did solve my issue though! So definitely needed like you said!)

Comment: I probably had a reference when I wrote that 4 years ago, but I don't remember it now. I haven't used Firefox for any web scraping since the great plugin massacre of Firefox 57.

Comment: For others wondering, this comment header is also required for [youtube-dl](https://youtube-dl.org/) to accept a cookie file with `--cookies mycookies.txt`

Answer (score 5):

One way of getting cookies for wget is to use the --keep-session-cookies options of wget.

For example :

```
wget --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies cookies.txt "http://MYSITE/?__login=USER&__password=PASS"
```

The `?__login etc` depends on the web site you're trying to mirror, you might have to look at how the authentication form works.

Then you can use :

```
wget --mirror --load-cookies cookies.txt http://MYSITE/
```

Comment: this doesn't answer the question of what the file format is